# react-native insert youtube video

Tags: react-native

I am trying to insert youtube video to my react-native project. I added- react-native-video library, then this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
 Text,
View,
Video
} from 'react-native';

export default class video extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Video source={{uri: "Gladiator trailer.mp4"}}
   ref={(ref) => {
     this.player = ref
   }}                             // Store reference
   rate={1.0}                     // 0 is paused, 1 is normal.
   volume={1.0}                   // 0 is muted, 1 is normal.
   muted={false}                  // Mutes the audio entirely.
   paused={false}                 // Pauses playback entirely.
   resizeMode="cover"             // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.
   repeat={true}                  // Repeat forever.
   playInBackground={false}       // Audio continues to play when app entering background.
   playWhenInactive={false}       // [iOS] Video continues to play when control or notification center are shown.
   progressUpdateInterval={250.0} // [iOS] Interval to fire onProgress (default to ~250ms)
   onLoadStart={this.loadStart}   // Callback when video starts to load
   onLoad={this.setDuration}      // Callback when video loads
   onProgress={this.setTime}      // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
   onEnd={this.onEnd}             // Callback when playback finishes
   onError={this.videoError}      // Callback when video cannot be loaded
   style={styles.backgroundVideo} />



);
    }
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundVideo: {
   position: 'absolute',
   top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  }
  });

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('video', () => video);
```

I am receiving this error: element type is invalid: expected a string (for build-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of 'video'.

Comment: where's the definition of methods like loadStart, setDuration ... ?

Comment: all settings corrected ?. If done, import Component and use.
Ref : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

Answer (score 0):

It throws that error when there's something wrong with a component you're returning in the render method. In this case I think it's your Video component, to my knowledge I don't believe there is a Video component provided by RN. If you're pulling it in from another library, make sure to import it from there and not RN.

For example:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
```